# Setting variable in a file does not work

Tags: bash

I have a file `run_me`

```
#!/bin/bash
export BOBO=MOMO
```

After I run `run_me`, the variable `BOBO` isn't set. Why? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to source it:

```
. ./run_me
```

OR

```
source ./run_me
```

In order to run this script in current shell otherwise BASH creates a new sub-shell and executes the script in that sub-shell therefore all the changes (variable etc) are not reflected in the current parent shell.

Comment: @devnull: Thanks so much for fixing the typo.

Comment: Too fast for me too, I quit :-)